# Set of images doesn't load (Masonry,Infinitescroll, ImagesLoaded)

Tags: javascript, safari, jquery-masonry

We have this bug only in Safari browser (on iPad and iPhone too).Basically, when user visit page, it would show him images with articles, if he scroll down, it would load new articles but images are missing.

The thing I noticed is that images are here, but their height is equal to 0 - probbably something related to the imagesLoaded plugin.Bellow is our CommonJS code

```
define([
    'imagesloaded',
    'masonry-layout',
    'vendor/infinitescroll'
], function(imagesLoaded, Masonry, infinitescroll){

    $(document).ready(function() { 

        'use strict';

        // Main content container
        let gridSelector    = 'div.Grid',
                $container      = $(gridSelector),
                itemSelector    = '.StandardArticle';

        // Masonry + ImagesLoaded
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container.layout = new Masonry(gridSelector, {
                itemSelector: itemSelector,
                percentPosition: true
            });
        });

        // Infinite Scroll
        $container.infinitescroll({
            navSelector: "#infinite_navigation",
            nextSelector: "#infinite_navigation a",
            itemSelector: itemSelector,
            dataType: 'html',
            path: [$('#infinite_navigation a').attr('href') + '?page=', ''],
            loadingImg: $('#infinite-loading-img').attr('src'),
            loading: {
              finishedMsg: 'All articles are loaded !'
            }
          },

            function( newElements ) {
                var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({opacity: 0});
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $newElems.animate({opacity: 1});
                    $container.layout.appended( $newElems );
                 });
            }
        );

    });

});
```

There are no nothing weird in our CSS - pretty basic structure.

Comment: try not to use imagesLoaded and check if work correctly

Comment: @MarwenJelloul still doesn't work.